# C# Unity changing variables within collision detection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

It is as if the system is unable to remember/keep changes to variables that are made during collisions. These variables are declared at the top of my code outside of the collisions. How can I fix this?

I am creating a game and trying to make it so that if a player touches an enemy the player loses health. However, the health only goes down during the collision and goes back to its full number after the collision.

```
 else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerHealth = playerHealth - 10;
        }
```

In a different situation, I am trying to make it so that a player can only use the bomb button if they actually have a bomb by setting a bool to true under a collision. Again, after the collision is over the bool goes back to false on its own.

Comment: You are probably resetting it somewhere. Please post the whole relevant code.

Comment: Hello, there are too many possibilities for your issue. The function you want to achieve is not complicated, and there are many examples on the Internet. But if you want to get targeted and effective help on the SO platform, you need to provide more information, such as your code.